# Matlab timeseries plot error

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink

I am having an issue when trying to plot these two timeseries against each other:

```
subplot(2,2,3),plot(wrm,Te);title('Speed-Torque curve');
xlabel('wrm [rad/s]');ylabel('Te[Nm]')
axis([-5 10 20 200]);
grid;
```

It comes up with the error of

```
Error using plot
A numeric or double convertible argument is expected

Error in timeseries/plot (line 163)
p = plot(ax,Time,Data,varargin{:});
```

I have tried changing the "to workspace" variables in simulink from 1x1 double timeseries to arrays and that seems to allow me to plot, but the plot for just Te become incorrect.

All other plots I create, I am unable to follow the format of plot(time,yvariable) as it gives the same error so I have been just using plot(yvariable) which has worked up until now.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. If you are trying to plot the data members of the two `timeseries` objects against each other, use

```
plot(wrm.Data, Te.Data);
```

If you are plotting the data members, you of course need to make sure these vectors are the same length. If they are not, you could use something like

```
Te2 = resample(Te2, wrm.Time);
```

If you want to plot both against time instead, use

```
plot(wrm); hold on; plot(Te);
```

Or, as I like to do:

```
wrm.plot(); hold on; Te.plot();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! You are correct in that I am trying to plot the two timeseries against each other. I am able to get the wrm vs Te plot to work now, I think the problem was the length. Only issue I am having now is that I am unable to plot the graph of Te using a subplot, could that be an issue from changing the variable to an array?